# C++: Data alignment and efficient use of memory (in both time and space)

Tags: c++

Cheers every!

I want to store some data in memory in a structure, or in an array. My problem is data alignment. I cant really use a 8 byte data next to a char since they will take up 16 bytes together.

Now I would live happy with a single 8 byte field, like a char and using the remaining 7 bytes to store other data.

How do I do that? What are the performance penalties to pay?
Thanks people.

Comment: What language, platform, compiler?

Comment: @Flinsch: C++, Windows, Mingw, but I prefer portable solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can automate the bit shifting math suggested by Arkku with bitfields:

```
struct {
    uint64_t  one_byte:8;
    uint64_t  seven_byte:56;
};
```

There will be slight access overhead but it's worth it if you plan to use so many of these that space is at a premium.  Over so much memory the improved cache locality will easily offset a few shift/mask operations.

Comment: Yo, man! I think that's the exact thing I need, how could I forget bit fields, haha! Is endiannes a matter here? PS: I would accept Arkku's answer too if I could.

Comment: If you plan to use bitfields to alias something else (like device registers) or save/read them as binary you might, but for the most part you can ignore it.  The only tricky part can be slightly different treatment for `int foo:8` vs `char foo`:  Even though they have the same storage capacity, some of the underlying int-ness shows through.  For example, at least at one point gcc didn't think `unsigned x:16` could "fit" inside a 32-bit `int` which would only come up in obscure cases.

Comment: I really would not do anything fancy with those fields, I just want to store two value, a char and a 7 byte value in them. Nothing to be afraid of then, methinks? Thank you again.

Comment: Yep, bitfields are nice but not portable, especially with large field sizes like this; on a 32-bit machine the compiler _could_ simply reject this. (In practice I doubt common compilers will.)

Answer (score 2):

With your 8-byte field, you can get the lowest 8 bits with `field & 0xFF` and the rest with `field >> 8`. To assign values you can similarly construct the field with `(seven << 8) | (one & 0xFF)` (you can omit the 0xFF here if you know `one` is only 8 bits).

The penalty is having to do these operations every time you use the data.

(As more of a hack, you may be able to access the one-byte part directly with casts, but then byte order within the 8-byte word will start to matter.)

Comment: Even with casting I would need to do some math with the 7 byte part, wouldn't I? Then I think I will go with cleaner option.